# Manually switch NavigationBar to Dark Mode

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios-darkmode

In my app I have a manual switch to go between light/dark modes and what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the navigation bar to have the "dark mode" appearance (White text/icons and black background) triggered when I need to switch between light/dark.

I have tried everything below:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor=UIColor.white

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor=UIColor.white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

And the navigation bar never changes when any of the code above I have tried is entered.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
}
```

Comment: You'r missing a `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against the wall for some time, I finally solved this issue (it may not be the same issue you're having, but hopefully this helps someone).
I had my navbar tint color set to "white". For the navbar color to change automatically when dark mode is enabled, it needs to be set to "default".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the bar to your own local dark mode with one easy line. But we can write a function that does something similar to what you want. Please note that the proper way to do this sort of thing is to add a switch on bar style and colors that use trait collection to change between the different global visual modes.

```
extension UIViewController {

    enum NavigationBarStyle {
        case dark, light
    }

    func setNavigationBar(style: NavigationBarStyle) {

        guard let bar = view.subviews.first(where: { return $0 is UINavigationBar }) as? UINavigationBar else { return }

        func set(item: UINavigationItem, color: UIColor) {
            item.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = color
            item.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = color
        }

        bar.barStyle = style == .dark ? .black : default

        let color: UIColor = style == .dark ? .white : .black
        for item in bar.items ?? [] {
            bar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: color]
            set(item: item, color: color)
        }

    }

}
```

You'll need to make sure that you've already added a navigation bar to the subview of the controller. I did something like this programmatically, but I imagine using the interface builder is just the same.

```
let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 45))

navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
navbar.delegate = self

let navItem = UINavigationItem()
navItem.title = "Title"
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

navbar.setItems([navItem], animated: true)

view.addSubview(navbar)
```

And then finally, set the style after some action or whatever you like. Using;

```
setNavigationBar(style: .dark)
```